# Getting Authentication Error while accessing Azure Blob table (wasb) URL using PySpark

Tags: python, azure, pyspark, azure-blob-storage, parquet

I am trying to access the Azure Blob table using Pyspark but getting an Authentication Error.
Here I am passing SAS token (HTTP and HTTPS enabled) but it's working only with WASBS (HTTPS) URL, not with WASB (HTTP) URL.

Code:

```
    from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
    spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()
    spark.conf.set("fs.azure.sas.<container-name>.<storage-account>.blob.core.windows.net","<
SAS Token>")
```

Error:

```
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o146.table.
: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.hadoop.fs.azure.AzureException: com.microsoft.azure.storage.StorageException: Cannot use HTTP with credentials that only support HTTPS.
    at org.sparkproject.guava.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture$Sync.getValue(AbstractFuture.java:306)
    at org.sparkproject.guava.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture$Sync.get(AbstractFuture.java:293)
    at org.sparkproject.guava.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.get(AbstractFuture.java:116)
    at org.sparkproject.guava.util.concurrent.Uninterruptibles.getUninterruptibly(Uninterruptibles.java:135)
    at org.sparkproject.guava.cache.LocalCache$Segment.getAndRecordStats(LocalCache.java:2410)
    at org.sparkproject.guava.cache.LocalCache$Segment.loadSync(LocalCache.java:2380)
    at org.sparkproject.guava.cache.LocalCache$Segment.lockedGetOrLoad(LocalCache.java:2342)
    at org.sparkproject.guava.cache.LocalCache$Segment.get(LocalCache.java:2257)
    at org.sparkproject.guava.cache.LocalCache.get(LocalCache.java:4000)
    at org.sparkproject.guava.cache.LocalCache$LocalManualCache.get(LocalCache.java:4789)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.catalog.SessionCatalog.getCachedPlan(SessionCatalog.scala:155)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FindDataSourceTable.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$FindDataSourceTable$$readDataSourceTable(DataSourceStrategy.scala:249)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FindDataSourceTable$$anonfun$apply$2.applyOrElse(DataSourceStrategy.scala:288)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FindDataSourceTable$$anonfun$apply$2.applyOrElse(DataSourceStrategy.scala:278)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper.$anonfun$resolveOperatorsDown$2(AnalysisHelper.scala:108)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.CurrentOrigin$.withOrigin(TreeNode.scala:74)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper.$anonfun$resolveOperatorsDown$1(AnalysisHelper.scala:108)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper$.allowInvokingTransformsInAnalyzer(AnalysisHelper.scala:221)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper.resolveOperatorsDown(AnalysisHelper.scala:106)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper.resolveOperatorsDown$(AnalysisHelper.scala:104)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.resolveOperatorsDown(LogicalPlan.scala:29)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper.$anonfun$resolveOperatorsDown$4(AnalysisHelper.scala:113)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.$anonfun$mapChildren$1(TreeNode.scala:408)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.mapProductIterator(TreeNode.scala:244)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.mapChildren(TreeNode.scala:406)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.mapChildren(TreeNode.scala:359)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper.$anonfun$resolveOperatorsDown$1(AnalysisHelper.scala:113)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper$.allowInvokingTransformsInAnalyzer(AnalysisHelper.scala:221)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper.resolveOperatorsDown(AnalysisHelper.scala:106)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper.resolveOperatorsDown$(AnalysisHelper.scala:104)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.resolveOperatorsDown(LogicalPlan.scala:29)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper.resolveOperators(AnalysisHelper.scala:73)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper.resolveOperators$(AnalysisHelper.scala:72)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.resolveOperators(LogicalPlan.scala:29)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FindDataSourceTable.apply(DataSourceStrategy.scala:278)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FindDataSourceTable.apply(DataSourceStrategy.scala:243)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.rules.RuleExecutor.$anonfun$execute$2(RuleExecutor.scala:216)
    at scala.collection.LinearSeqOptimized.foldLeft(LinearSeqOptimized.scala:126)
    at scala.collection.LinearSeqOptimized.foldLeft$(LinearSeqOptimized.scala:122)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foldLeft(List.scala:89)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.rules.RuleExecutor.$anonfun$execute$1(RuleExecutor.scala:213)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.rules.RuleExecutor.$anonfun$execute$1$adapted(RuleExecutor.scala:205)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:392)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.rules.RuleExecutor.execute(RuleExecutor.scala:205)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer.org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$analysis$Analyzer$$executeSameContext(Analyzer.scala:196)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer.execute(Analyzer.scala:190)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer.execute(Analyzer.scala:155)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.rules.RuleExecutor.$anonfun$executeAndTrack$1(RuleExecutor.scala:183)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.QueryPlanningTracker$.withTracker(QueryPlanningTracker.scala:88)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.rules.RuleExecutor.executeAndTrack(RuleExecutor.scala:183)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer.$anonfun$executeAndCheck$1(Analyzer.scala:174)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper$.markInAnalyzer(AnalysisHelper.scala:228)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer.executeAndCheck(Analyzer.scala:173)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.$anonfun$analyzed$1(QueryExecution.scala:73)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.QueryPlanningTracker.measurePhase(QueryPlanningTracker.scala:111)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.$anonfun$executePhase$1(QueryExecution.scala:143)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.withActive(SparkSession.scala:775)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.executePhase(QueryExecution.scala:143)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.analyzed$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:73)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.analyzed(QueryExecution.scala:71)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.assertAnalyzed(QueryExecution.scala:63)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$.$anonfun$ofRows$1(Dataset.scala:90)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.withActive(SparkSession.scala:775)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$.ofRows(Dataset.scala:88)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.table(DataFrameReader.scala:891)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.fs.azure.AzureException: com.microsoft.azure.storage.StorageException: Cannot use HTTP with credentials that only support HTTPS.
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.azure.AzureNativeFileSystemStore.retrieveMetadata(AzureNativeFileSystemStore.java:2152)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.azure.NativeAzureFileSystem.getFileStatusInternal(NativeAzureFileSystem.java:2660)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.azure.NativeAzureFileSystem.getFileStatus(NativeAzureFileSystem.java:2605)
    at org.apache.hudi.common.util.TablePathUtils.getTablePath(TablePathUtils.java:50)
    at org.apache.hudi.DataSourceUtils.getTablePath(DataSourceUtils.java:75)
    at org.apache.hudi.DefaultSource.createRelation(DefaultSource.scala:84)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.resolveRelation(DataSource.scala:353)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FindDataSourceTable.$anonfun$readDataSourceTable$1(DataSourceStrategy.scala:261)
    at org.sparkproject.guava.cache.LocalCache$LocalManualCache$1.load(LocalCache.java:4792)
    at org.sparkproject.guava.cache.LocalCache$LoadingValueReference.loadFuture(LocalCache.java:3599)
    at org.sparkproject.guava.cache.LocalCache$Segment.loadSync(LocalCache.java:2379)
    ... 70 more
Caused by: com.microsoft.azure.storage.StorageException: Cannot use HTTP with credentials that only support HTTPS.
    at com.microsoft.azure.storage.core.ExecutionEngine.setupStorageRequest(ExecutionEngine.java:341)
    at com.microsoft.azure.storage.core.ExecutionEngine.executeWithRetry(ExecutionEngine.java:80)
    at com.microsoft.azure.storage.blob.CloudBlob.exists(CloudBlob.java:1994)
    at com.microsoft.azure.storage.blob.CloudBlob.exists(CloudBlob.java:1981)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.azure.StorageInterfaceImpl$CloudBlobWrapperImpl.exists(StorageInterfaceImpl.java:333)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.azure.AzureNativeFileSystemStore.retrieveMetadata(AzureNativeFileSystemStore.java:2087)
    ... 80 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot use HTTP with credentials that only support HTTPS.
    at com.microsoft.azure.storage.StorageCredentialsSharedAccessSignature.transformUri(StorageCredentialsSharedAccessSignature.java:108)
    at com.microsoft.azure.storage.StorageCredentialsSharedAccessSignature.transformUri(StorageCredentialsSharedAccessSignature.java:141)
    at com.microsoft.azure.storage.blob.CloudBlob.getTransformedAddress(CloudBlob.java:2413)
    at com.microsoft.azure.storage.blob.CloudBlob$11.buildRequest(CloudBlob.java:2011)
    at com.microsoft.azure.storage.blob.CloudBlob$11.buildRequest(CloudBlob.java:2001)
    at com.microsoft.azure.storage.core.ExecutionEngine.setupStorageRequest(ExecutionEngine.java:313)
    ... 85 more
```

The other way is working fine if I try to load the parquet file by passing the WASB URL, but this method is very slow and takes too much time to access the data.

Please help me understand why PySpark-Azure showing such behavior.

We had a meeting with the Azure support team as well but they also couldn't find any issue from their end.

Comment: does your storage account configured with https only?

Comment: No, and one more thing that same setup is working fine if we do a query from Presto. Even though I have tried with Account key in place of SAS token but got same error, so seems its related to PySpark, pls help.

Answer (score 0):

I got same error in my environment. I just enabled secure transfer, after that working fine didn’t get any authentication Error.

[image: Ref1]

**Sample code:**

```
spark.conf.set(
  "fs.azure.sas.<container_name>.<storage_account_name>.blob.core.windows.net",
  "<SAS Token>")
```

[image: Ref2]

for more details follow this [reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/data/data-sources/azure/azure-storage#access-azure-blob-storage-using-the-dataframe-api) provided by Microsoft